# Not Able to find the torrc file in mac for tor browser

Tags: macos, proxy, configuration, tor, tor-browser-bundle

I am not able to find the torrc file in my mac.

I have mac with OS version 12.3.1 Montery.

Can someone please advice me on this ?

I have tried finding the /Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/torrc but this location is not present in my mac.

I also want to know how can I do this in windows OS as well?

My Goal is to change exit location to certain country but not sure how can I do this ? I think it will be possible with torrc file but could not find one..

Answer (score 0):

when I re-installed the tor browser that option of directory came up in my application support directory and then I changed the torrc file with exit nodes.

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem? You can then give more details (exact steps needed) and accept your answer. Else, this should be a comment or an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 using MacOS Ventura, To locate the `torrc` do the following:

- Open up Finder and use the keyboard shortcut `⌘+shift+g`
- Next, enter `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/`
- Double-click on the `Tor` directory and you'll see the `torrc` file.

I hope this helps out.